# Q: mitmproxy - negotiate TLS downgrade on internal NIC?

Tags: tls1.2, mitmproxy, tls1.3

I am completely new to mitmproxy and I'm working my way through the docs, but I have a specific requirement from my management in picking a proxy to work with.  Specifically we need the ability to accept an incoming (outbound/external facing) connection using TLS 1.3 (and 1.2 of course), but after decryption and inspection, the backend connection to the server is made in TLS 1.2 even if the incoming connect was in 1.3.  An additional requirement is to control the ciphers that can be negotiated on either side.  Is there a way to configure mitmproxy to work in this kind of non-symmetric connection mode?

I found notes that indicate:

```
tls_version_client_max
mitmproxy mitmdump mitmweb  str Set the maximum TLS version for client connections.
Default: UNBOUNDED
Choices: UNBOUNDED, SSL3, TLS1_1, TLS1_2, TLS1_3

tls_version_client_min
mitmproxy mitmdump mitmweb  str Set the minimum TLS version for client connections.
Default: TLS1_2
Choices: UNBOUNDED, SSL3, TLS1_1, TLS1_2, TLS1_3

tls_version_server_max
mitmproxy mitmdump mitmweb  str Set the maximum TLS version for server connections.
Default: UNBOUNDED
Choices: UNBOUNDED, SSL3, TLS1_1, TLS1_2, TLS1_3

tls_version_server_min
mitmproxy mitmdump mitmweb  str Set the minimum TLS version for server connections.
Default: TLS1_2
Choices: UNBOUNDED, SSL3, TLS1_1, TLS1_2, TLS1_3
```

and this would seem to imply that I could set the client side to TLS1_2, TLS1_3 and the server side to TLS1_2 only.  Would this accomplish my goal?

Answer (score 0):

mitmproxy will by default try to negotiate the highest available TLS version on both connections independently. That means if your client supports TLS 1.3 and your server only supports TLS 1.2, you will have a TLS 1.3 connection between client and proxy, and a TLS 1.2 connection between proxy and server. Long story short, you should not need to make any changes.

The options you listed allow you to change that behavior, either by increasing or lowering the required minimum version, or by restricting the maximum version (if you want to insist on speaking 1.2 with a TLS 1.3-capable server).